# C++ : Library for creating 3d view picture

Tags: c++, data, image-processing

I've got a numerical simulation, where I have as an output 3d matrix of billion elements - the visualisation of data is 2d flat image:

[image]

When I was starting I was just outputting 2d data to gnuplot, now I generate png file in program itself (to cut generation time). I would like now to get a 3d picture (in flat png) from my billion elements 3d matrix - in isotropic view etc. I found on the Internet things like ImLib3d for image processing, but I am afraid it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: What primitives are you drawing? Do you need depth buffering? Do you expect to use some form of blending, if so would it be additive or alpha blending? Etc, please provide at least, like, something slightly relevant to your question.

Comment: So you essentially have a 1000x1000x1000 lattice with samples on each lattice point, and want to construct some sort of volumetric view on it?

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking *how* you could render this data or are you asking for a library to do so? The latter is off-topic here.

Comment: I've got a software renderer you could use.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the easiest way here is to just learn some more advanced math and render needed isometric image into `.png` pixel by pixel.

Of course, you can learn something like OpenGL for this, but this library can be hard to learn. Also, using it will require more code, you will get your results faster.